# header image won't scale/stretch to full-width when it's set as background

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to get the parallax effect on a header, but the header needs to stretch a little bit to reach full-width. What I want is the following code, but I need the image to be set as background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <img width="100%" height="600px" src="https://nebula.wsimg.com/d392c606f7dba3537a83d91d90f4c7a2?AccessKeyId=BF7FD28E4BC0A4D7650A&disposition=0&alloworigin=1">
    </header>

    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried using background-size: cover, background-size: contain, and several other options to make it stretch to full width as a background-image, but the only way I can do it is manually setting pixels for background-size which is not dynamic.

Here's a codepen of what I'm trying to have the picture look like: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOpLGW  (Notice it's stretched to full-width

Here's my attempt to make it work with css as a background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="parallaxImage">
    </header>

    <div style="height: 2000px; text-align: center;">Just parallaxing</div>

    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#parallaxImage {
  background-image: url('https://nebula.wsimg.com/d392c606f7dba3537a83d91d90f4c7a2?AccessKeyId=BF7FD28E4BC0A4D7650A&disposition=0&alloworigin=1');
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  /*background-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%; */
  background-size: 1300px 600px; /* I've tried cover and contain */
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqYzBQ  (neither cover nor contain work. background-size: 1300px 600px is pretty close but won't account for different screen sizes.)

It doesn't really look right in CodePen, but it looks fine in a full browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
#parallaxImage {
    ...
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
</style>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXMojb)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#parallaxImage {
  background-size: 100% 600px;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a margin 0 to the body to get rid of the extra space on top and sides.

you can force the size of #parallaxImage to the size of the image with padding-top. see the comments in the css to see how you can calculate what the padding-top should be.

this way your image will be responsive and never stretched out of proportion.

i hope this is what you are asking for.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

#parallaxImage {
    /* 
    width of image / height of image * width
    668px / 1001px * 50  = 33.3666333666
    (change the 50 in this formula to whatever you want.)
    */
    padding-top: 33.3666333666%;
    background-image: url('https://nebula.wsimg.com/d392c606f7dba3537a83d91d90f4c7a2?AccessKeyId=BF7FD28E4BC0A4D7650A&disposition=0&alloworigin=1');
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<header id="parallaxImage"></header>

<p>Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla </p>
```